# get latest path based on name-date from a list python

Tags: python, github

I want to extract the path with the latest day from this list in order to read it in the python script.

```
 from github.MainClass import Github
 g = Github("****")
 repo = g.get_repo("CSSEGISandData/COVID-19")
 file_list = repo.get_contents("csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports")
 github_dir_path = 'https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/raw/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/'
```

The output of file_list:

[ContentFile(path="csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/.gitignore"),
ContentFile(path="csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/01-01-2021.csv"),
ContentFile(path="csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/01-02-2021.csv"),
ContentFile(path="csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/01-03-2021.csv"),
ContentFile(path="csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/01-04-2021.csv"),....

and what I need is for example: "csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/11-27-2021.csv" .

Comment: Post the list and explain what is the required item .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do 3 things:

1. Filter out any files that do not end with '.csv'.
2. Parse the relevant part of the filename as a date.
3. Sort the list of data files by the parsed date.

```py
from github.MainClass import Github
from datetime import datetime


# 2. parsing the name attribute of a ContentFile object as a datetime object
def to_date(s):
    return datetime.strptime(s.name[:10], "%m-%d-%Y")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    g = Github()
    repo = g.get_repo("CSSEGISandData/COVID-19")
    data_files = repo.get_contents("csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports")

    # 1. filter to use only data files
    data_files = [f for f in data_files if f.name.endswith('.csv')]

    # 3. sort according to parsed date
    data_files = sorted(data_files, key=to_date)

    github_dir_path = 'https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/raw/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/'

    for data_file in data_files:
        print(data_file)

    current_data = data_files[-1]
    print("\n" + " Current Data: ".center(80, "#"))
    print(f"path: {current_data.path}")
```

Output reads:

```
...

ContentFile(path="csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/11-26-2021.csv")
ContentFile(path="csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/11-27-2021.csv")

################################ Current Data: #################################
path: csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/11-27-2021.csv
```

Comment: @Pro23 You are welcome. I wish you the best of luck with your research.